# Uninstalling gcc

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to uninstall my gcc by terminal. When I type

```
gcc --version
```

The output is

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Could anyone help me? How can I install the last version of gcc after that?

Comment: This question is not about C++, so don't tag C++.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following command (Replace <version> with the appropriate version):

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove gcc-<version>
```

You can install a specific version of a program using apt, you can use the following command. (Replace <version> with the appropriate version)

```
sudo apt-get install gcc=<version>
```

Alternatively, you can use **[Synaptic Package Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/synaptic/)**.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Note that, you might need GCC for some programs. If you face any driver issues while installing programs / drivers you can install the latest GCC by using:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Comment: What should I type to install last version of gcc?

Comment: You can use synaptic package manager. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @LakshmikantDeshpande why do you say it's dangerous to uninstall GCC in Ubuntu? The only problem I can see is if you have drivers that require on DKMS.

Comment: That's why I was suggesting that it is a dangerous command. (nvidia drivers in my case).
Thanks  :)